# asp.net mvc Keep Session alive with setInterval

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I have button click event that takes long time to process (>60 mins). I am trying to use setInterval event to keep my session alive.

```
function OnButtonClick(s, e, startUrl, progressUrl) {
    StartActionOnServer(startUrl);
    setInterval(keepalive, 2000);
}

function keepalive()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ImportData/alive',
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "text",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr)
            },
        });
     }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult alive()
    {
        var result = "I am pinging the server";
        return Content(result);
    }
```

Problem here is that, I want `setInterval(keepalive, 2000);` to run while `StartActionOnServer(startUrl);` is running for about 1 hour. This is to keep my view refreshed. This is not happening now. my Console.log looks like:

[image]

I would like it to look .

```
I am pinging the server.
I am pinging the server.
I am pinging the server.
I am done
```

Any idea how can this be achieved. Appreciate help.

Update:
Added other methods being used:

```
function StartActionOnServer(startUrl) {
        positionDate = ReportingPositionDate.GetDate().toDateString();
        myProgressBar.Show;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: startUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
                ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
                lpImport.Hide();
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr);
            }
        });
    }
```

Button Click event:

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ OnButtonClick(s, e, '{0}', '{1}'); }}", Url.Action("Start", "ImportData", null), Url.Action("alive", "ImportData", null));
```

Controller Star action looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Start()
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
        //Thread.Sleep(3600000);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        //var result = new { StartResult = "DataFileUpload failed" };
        var ReturnVal = "I am done";
        progress = 0;
        return Content(ReturnVal);
        //return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: `StartActionOnServer` is `async` operation? and where you are planning to put `I am done`? Also I don't see any `clear interval` part!!

Comment: Yes, StarActionOnServer is async.  "I am done" is part of StartActionOnServer(startUrl); which calls an Action Start() and return Content("I am done").  Let me add the code.

Comment: How about putting `setInterval` above the `StartActionOnServer`??

Comment: I tried that, but same output :(